# How to call and save the result set of oracle stored procedure which returns ref cursor in a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to call a existing procedure in my new procedure:

Retrievedata returns a OUT sys_refcursor

I am trying to save the output result of Retrievedata procedure.

```
TYPE Doc IS REF CURSOR;
Doc := PKG_search.Retrievedata(IN_Id);
```

I am getting the following error:

> PLS-00321: expression 'DOC' is inappropriate as the left hand side of an assignment statement

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't hurt if you posted some more info. My lucky guess is:

Function that returns refcursor (if you do have a procedure, it has to have an OUT parameter, but - that's not what code you posted suggests):

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_deptno in number)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open l_rc for select ename, job
  7                  from emp
  8                  where deptno = par_deptno;
  9    return l_rc;
 10  end;
 11  /

Function created.
```

Procedure which uses that function, gets refcursor and displays it contents:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_deptno in number)
  2  is
  3    l_rc sys_refcursor;
  4    --
  5    l_ename emp.ename%type;
  6    l_job   emp.job%type;
  7  begin
  8    l_rc := f_test(par_deptno);
  9
 10    loop
 11      fetch l_rc into l_ename, l_job;
 12      exit when l_rc%notfound;
 13      dbms_output.put_line(l_ename ||' - '|| l_job);
 14    end loop;
 15    close l_rc;
 16  end;
 17  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec p_test(10);
CLARK - MANAGER
KING - PRESIDENT
MILLER - CLERK

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

If it *is* a procedure with an OUT parameter, then:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_one (par_deptno in number, par_out out sys_refcursor)
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    open par_out for select ename, job
  5                 from emp
  6                 where deptno = par_deptno;
  7  end;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_deptno in number)
  2  is
  3    l_rc sys_refcursor;
  4    --
  5    l_ename emp.ename%type;
  6    l_job   emp.job%type;
  7  begin
  8    p_one (par_deptno, l_rc);
  9
 10    loop
 11      fetch l_rc into l_ename, l_job;
 12      exit when l_rc%notfound;
 13      dbms_output.put_line(l_ename ||' - '|| l_job);
 14    end loop;
 15    close l_rc;
 16  end;
 17  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec p_test(10);
CLARK - MANAGER
KING - PRESIDENT
MILLER - CLERK

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.It has a procedure with out parameter.

Comment: OK. So - did you see the 2nd example I posted? It is a procedure with an OUT parameter.